# One-line alternative for xp_cmdshell? I tried several things

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Hello Microsoft SQL Server Masters,

Well, I have an Microsoft SQL Server 2000 as described below:

```
Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2039 (Intel X86) 
May  3 2005 23:18:38 
Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation
Desktop Engine on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

I need to execute an Operating System command from this Microsoft SQL Server, I checked that I have sysadmin privileges with the query below and it returned "1", which confirm my privilege.

```
SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin', 'sa');
```

I tried the traditional xp_cmdshell and nothing happened, just to make sure it was working I tried the famous:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\'; EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell "dir c:\";
```

And all returned NOTHING, which make me believe that xp_cmdshell is not available. I know that xp_cmdshell comes disable by default in Microsoft SQL Server 2005, but not in 2000, anyway, I tried to reenable it on the same way but it failed.

I looked at internet and I found this way to reenable xp_cmdshell for Microsoft SQL Server 2000:

```
exec sp_addextendedproc 'xp_cmdshell', 'xplog70.dll'

exec sp_addextendedproc xp_cmdshell, 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Binn\xplog70.dll'
```

However, it still doesn't work. I found another article telling that sometimes admins delete this files and I think it may be my case, the article says that if it was deleted I can execute "xp_msver" and in my case it also return nothing.

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/891984

I also tried this query that I found on the internet to see if xp_cmdshell exist and it returned nothing (but it may be a limitation of my weird SQL client, see below please).

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N’[dbo].[ xp_cmdshell]‘) and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N’IsExtendedProc’) = 1);
```

So, I'm really in trouble, I researched at Google and found potential solutions such as Job agent, SSIS package, CLR stored procedure, sp_OACreate (and friends) and SQLCMD but nothing worked. Maybe I did it incorrect, but another limitation in my case is that I just have access to this Microsoft SQL Server 2000 from a jump-box (Linux) that has a very odd sql-server client that do not accept queries with multiple lines, consequently I can't try with success the following potential solutions:

1# Job Agent

```
DECLARE @jobID uniqueidentifier, @cmd varchar(1000) 

SET @cmd = 'netstat -na > c:\connections.txt'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name = '_tmp_MakeDirectory', @enabled  = 1, @start_step_id = 1, @owner_login_name='sa', @job_id = @jobID OUTPUT 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @jobID, @step_name = 'Create Backup Folder', @step_id = 1, @subsystem = 'CMDEXEC', @command = @cmd

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobID

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id = @jobID, @output_flag = 0 

WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:05' -- Give the job a chance to complete

IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = '_tmp_MakeDirectory')
BEGIN
     EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = '_tmp_MakeDirectory'
END
```

2# SQLCMD

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SQLCMD_TEST
AS
    !!MKDIR "netstat -na > c:\connections.txt"
    :OUT "C:\TEST\test.TXT"
    SELECT @@VERSION AS 'SERVER VERSION'
    !!DIR
GO
    SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'SERVER NAME'
GO 


EXEC SQLCMD_TEST
```

Unfortunately I don't have any other way to access this Microsoft SQL Server, I know it's not the best way, but it's how it's and I can't do anything. So, I need a solution to execute Operating System commands on this Microsoft SQL Server 2000 with all this limitations. Can someone port any of the two above methods for one single line query, please?

Any other suggestion with example is very welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Regards.

Comment: What's the error you see when you run one of the last two options?

Comment: "... another limitation in my case is that I just have access to this Microsoft SQL Server 2000 from a jump-box (Linux) that has a very odd sql-server client that do not accept queries with multiple lines, ..." this sounds disturbingly like Injection-Hacking.

Comment: Hi Vince.

I don't see any answer, it just returns to the prompt. Any idea?

Comment: Hi RBarryYoung,

It's not a injection hacking, I do have the sa password and if you want send me any query that requires it and I will prove it.

Thanks

Comment: Does "PRINT 'Foo'" work?

Comment: Oh, and how long can the command line be for this odd sql client?

Comment: RBarryYoung, I respect you and I expect you to respect me, if you don't have nothing to contribute it's OK, but please, do not post just to troll.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not.  Seriously.  Whether the PRINT command works correctly is very important in diagnosing this problem.  It is entirely possible that xp_cmdshell *IS* working, but that your Linux client just isn't showing you the output.  PRINT sends the same kind of output that sp_cmdshell does (non-tabular, secondary channel) so it's a good test of that.  (and FYI, most simple clients do *not* capture this kind of output).

Comment: And the length of text that your accepts client is also important, because SQL is like C (java, etc.) in that you can string many commands together on the same line, if it can be long enough. (it does not use semicolons for this either).

Comment: RBarryYoung, thanks and sorry if I misunderstood your point. It never returned properly. I convinced my customer to install sqsh and now one of the methods described on my post worked and your test too.

1> PRINT 'Foo'
2> go
Foo
1> 

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use xp_cmdshell before CLR support came along. Unfortunately, you are a version away from CLR support (SQL Server 2005) and the system.io namespace. You can, however, create your own extended stored procedures which can access the file system and create directories. See here for more info: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/SQL-Server/Extended-Stored-Procedures-Intro-And-10-Cool-Examples/

By the way, xp_cmdshell is an extended stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks Brian for your help, I convinced my customer to install sqsh and now one of the methods described on my post worked.

BTW, this CLR support and also this create your own xp_cmdshell appears to be very interesting, if you have working examples and want to post here I'm pretty sure it will be helpful to someone.

Thank you very much.